# What is a good logging library for real-time systems (fast with no object creation)?

Tags: java, linux, optimization, garbage-collection, real-time

I tried logback but it created a ton of garbage. Does anyone heard about a good one for real-time Java?

---

@Bernie: I did a loop logging 1M cached messages and the GC went crazy.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" so I have downvoted.  If you edit with your research to date -- that way the entire community benefits -- then I will promptly remove downvote. Thank you, and best of luck with your issue.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnPristine. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look on [CoralLog](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/corallog/) designed by Coral Blocks (with which I am affiliated) that produces zero garbage and has an average latency of 53 nanoseconds when logging a 64-byte message. In terms of throughput, it can log 2.6 million 64-byte messages per second *with timestamps* and 3.5 million 64-byte messages per second *without timestamps*. The complete benchmark results can be seen [here](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/04/corallog-performance-numbers/).

If you reduce the message size to 16 bytes then you can log 5.2 million messages per second without timestamps.

Below is a simple throughput test:

```
package com.coralblocks.corallog.bench;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import com.coralblocks.corallog.AsyncThread;
import com.coralblocks.corallog.Log;
import com.coralblocks.corallog.Logger;

public class PerformanceTest4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int batchSize = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int passes = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int msgSize = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        byte[] msgBytes = new byte[msgSize];

        // build a dummy message:
        for(int i = 0; i < msgBytes.length; i++) {
             msgBytes[i] = (byte) String.valueOf(i % 10).charAt(0);
        }

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(msgBytes);

        Log.setIncludeTopHeader(false);

        String dir = ".";
        String filename = "throughput.log";

        Logger logger;
        boolean isMmap = System.getProperty("logMemoryMappedFile", "true").equals("true");

        if (isMmap) {
            logger = Log.createMemoryMappedLogger(dir, filename, null /* no timestamps */, false /* not synchronized */, true /* asynchronous */);
        } else {
            logger = Log.createLogger(dir, filename, null, false, true);
        }

        int count = 0;

        while(count < passes) {

            long start = System.nanoTime();

            for(int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
            bb.position(0);
            logger.log(bb);
            }

            long time = System.nanoTime() - start;

            double seconds = (((double) time) / 1000000000L);

            System.out.println("Batch " + (count + 1) + " took: " + seconds + " s");

            count++;
        }

        logger.drainCloseAndWait();

        boolean deleteFile = System.getProperty("deleteFile", "true").equals("true");

        if (deleteFile) {
            File f = new File(dir, filename);
            f.delete();
        }

        AsyncThread.drainAndDie(); // just so the vm will exit... (async thread is not daemon)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I have a library which can log text or binary data in under a micro-second without creating garbage or even a system call.

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

The log can also be read in real time by any number of reading processes, giving you a persisted queue which can handle over 5 million messages per second.

Comment: I use memory mapped files, so there is a system call per 16MB - 1 GB written, not per message. I have a test writing 20 M short binary messages per second, and 5 million medium sized text messages. On a 4.5 Ghz i7 I got 4 different file writes with real data in 700 nanosecond. The home pages has lists of the performance stats. I found the system call writes take about 3 micro-seconds also which is why I came up with a way to avoid them. ;)

Comment: The most difficult one to write efficiently is dates and doubles. Do you have any performance stats for writing doubles? (The 5 M/second of text includes a date/time and a double)

Comment: memory mapped files don't need to be flushed to disk to protect from the failure of an application (failure of the OS, or disk, is different)  This is because the OS knows how to pass the data to disk, even if the process has died.

Comment: The problem with Asynchronous logging is it adds its own overhead of copying data between threads and doing it in a GC free way is tricky. I have done it with `Exchanger<ByteBuffer>` but its not as fast and the latencies and much higher as you cannot predict when the data, if ever will be written.

Comment: Basically if you can write data faster using one thread instead of two, I would use just one.

Comment: BTW: Its isn't write only, the data can be read randomly and re-written (though you can't change the length of a line/message)

Comment: The problem space I have is a little different, but the 700 ns timing is the time taken to write a message in one process, a second process picks up that message, writes or updates two records, writes a response and the first process reads the response, i.e. the end to end time from the first processes point of view. The latency of every hop is critical not just the average timing over one million messages.

Comment: With a memory mapped file you can tail it while its being written, but you need a specific program to do it (which I have added to the library) as the file grows in chunks (which is part of the reason its so fast) I don't see asynchronous logging and messaging as that different. For logging you are writing text or journally in binary in a persisted, re-readable way as fast as possible. With asynchronous messaging, you also want machine readability. I have used a text protocol for messaging before and it reads just like logs. BTW: Every message is kept just like logging.

Comment: For network communication, it uses the notion of replication.  It has a server which runs on the source of messages and a client which runs on the sinks. This supports a one to many fan out.  There will be a copy on the writer and all the readers.  Reading processes can then the files as if they were local and if any part needs to restart it can contnue from where it was up to.

Comment: You are right. Fortunately a complete replay batches very nicely and bandwidth is often your limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Javolution provides logging capabilities.

From the LogContext javadoc:

> The same code can run using system out/err, standard logging
>   (java.util.logging), Log4J or even OSGI Log services. Selection can be
>   done at run-time through `configuration`).

('`configuration`' refers to a Javolution class).